# Why are the 'things' that are created from human transmutation so randomly generated?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series

This has been bugging me for a while but why are the 'things' that are created from human transmutation (Which has been stated is impossible) so randomly generated.

Ed and Al set out to transmute their dead mother but turns out to create some weird thing which was later identified to be some random male with black hair.

[image: Result of Eric and Al's human transmutation attempt]

If anything why doesn't the end result of the transmutation be something more similar to what they initially wanted to revive? Why male not female? Why black hair not brown hair?

Additionally, what are they actually, other than failed outcomes of human transmutation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Essentially, human transmutation was depicted to be impossible to do.

The reason why it doesn't look what they intended it to look like is because they just screwed up that hard.

What they ended up with was something kinda sorta vaguely human, but only barely.

From looking at the picture you've posted, a lot of the pieces of a human are there, but they're not all correctly done and they're not all in the right place. It really doesn't look that random to me; if anything, it looks like a predictable (while still major) screw-up.

Comment: "It really doesn't look that random to me" but something else occured when the gold-teeth doctor was transmutated at the end of BH.

Comment: @ZoltánSchmidt That's because Pride and Mustang knew almost nothing about Human Transmutation, and Mustang was there against his will; it makes sense that the two of them would not be able to produce something remotely human.